# Inverse projection mapping with camera orientation + coordinates (OpenCV)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, projection, camera-calibration, map-projections

So I know you can get a birds-eye view/ inverse projection with 4 points in an image but I will not have 4 points available for the task I need to achieve however I should have the exact position and orientation. I want to take pictures from a specific position and angle or a flat maze and apply an inverse perspective transform similar to this [here](https://shin-yamashita.github.io/mouse/mm72D-imgproc.html%20I%20want%20to%20achieve%20something%20similar%20to%20what%20is%20seen%20here.)

However my attempts at implementing this have all failed. I have tried doing it manually with `numpy` as you've seen below and also feeding a matrix to `cv2.perspectiveWarp`. Both have failed and I don't really understand why.

```py
    import numpy as np
    import cv2
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
    
    def uv2xy(frame, theta, phi,alpha,r_c):
        x_c,y_c,z_c=r_c
        TARGET_W =10*100
        TARGET_H =6*100
     
        f=3.6e-3 
        mu=2.2e-6
        mv=2.2e-6
        input_h, input_w,_ = frame.shape
        output=np.zeros((TARGET_W,TARGET_H,3),dtype=np.uint8)
        #Other matrix
        M = np.array([[np.sin(theta), -np.cos(theta), 0],
                      [np.cos(phi)*np.cos(theta),np.cos(phi)*np.sin(theta), np.sin(phi)],
                      [np.sin(phi)*np.cos(theta),np.sin(phi)*np.sin(theta), -np.cos(phi)]])
        
        
        K=np.array([[f*mu,0,mu*TARGET_W/2],
                    [0,f*mv,mv*TARGET_H/2],
                    [0,0,1]])
       
        for y in range(0,TARGET_H):
            for x in range(0,TARGET_W):
                x*=0.02
                y*=0.02
                u,v,w= K @ M @ np.array([x,y,0-z_c]).T
                u=u/w
                v=v/w
                x/=0.02
                y/=0.02
               
                if u>=0 and u<input_w and v>=0 and v<input_h:
                    #print("

{u,v}",np.floor(u).astype(int),",",np.floor(v).astype(int),"{x,y}",np.floor(x).astype(int),",",np.floor(y).astype(int),"RGB",frame[np.floor(v).astype(int),np.floor(u).astype(int)])
                    output[np.floor(x).astype(int),np.floor(y).astype(int)]=frame[np.floor(u).astype(int),np.floor(v).astype(int),]
       
     
    
        return output
    
    
    frame=cv2.imread("MVM.png")
    
    #uv2xy params
    
    
    
    z_c=1# z axis coordinate of camera
    x_c=0
    y_c=0
    alpha=np.radians(45) #camera fov in rad
    phi=np.rad2deg(80) #camera elevation relative to x-y plane in rad
    theta=np.rad2deg(-45)#camera azimuth angle in rad based on x axis direction
    r_c=(x_c,y_c,z_c)
    cv2.imshow("ada",frame)
    cv2.imshow("sdad",uv2xy(frame, theta, phi, alpha, r_c))
    print("done")
    #plt.show()
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```